# The Modal do not display after pressing twice in the same row

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Enable to click the same button Open Modal, in the same row, again after closing modal. In the end you have pressed the button twice in the same row.  Every time when you press the button a modal will appear.

Problem:
When I tried pressing the button again,in the same row, the modal do not display.
I do not understand why it cannot display the same modal again after pressing the same button in the same row.

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5bnxmy?

Thank you!

---

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';
import DisplayModalContent from './displayModalContent';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <DisplayModalContent item={openItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.setAppElement(document.getElementById('root'));
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

displayModalContent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class displayModalContent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(s) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(s)) {
      this.setState({ openItem: this.props.item });
    }
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {openItem !== null && (
          <Modal className="confirmation-modal" isOpen={true}>
            First Name:
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={openItem.firstName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              value={openItem.lastName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
            />
            <Select
              defaultValue={options.find(
                option => option.value === openItem.startMonth
              )}
              name="startMonth"
              id="testaaa"
              options={options}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Test</button>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default displayModalContent;
```

---

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
  opacity: 1;

  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content {
  position: absolute;

  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content--after-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirmation-modal button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the closeModal event back to the parent, so the openItem remains populated and no rerender of the parent occurs. You can fix this easily enough by adding an `onClose` prop that takes a callback:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v15ddy?file=src%2Findex.js